# Call dynamically created variables with LESS

Tags: variables, dynamic, less

Let's say i generate some variables which have been created with mixin...Like that:

```
@grey:                  lighten(@black, 50%);

.generate-color-shades(
    @color,
    @shades: 10%
) {
    @{color}-50:  darken(@color, (@shades * 4.9));
    @{color}-100: darken(@color, (@shades * 4.5));
    @{color}-150: darken(@color, (@shades * 4.2));
    @{color}-200: darken(@color, (@shades * 3.5));
    @{color}-250: darken(@color, (@shades * 3));
    @{color}-300: darken(@color, (@shades * 2.5));
    @{color}-350: darken(@color, (@shades * 2));
    @{color}-400: darken(@color, (@shades * 1.5));
    @{color}-450: darken(@color, (@shades));
    @{color}-500: @color;
    @{color}-550: lighten(@color, (@shades));
    @{color}-600: lighten(@color, (@shades * 1.5));
    @{color}-650: lighten(@color, (@shades * 2));
    @{color}-700: lighten(@color, (@shades * 2.5));
    @{color}-750: lighten(@color, (@shades * 3));
    @{color}-800: lighten(@color, (@shades * 3.5));
    @{color}-850: lighten(@color, (@shades * 4.2));
    @{color}-900: lighten(@color, (@shades * 4.5));
    @{color}-950: lighten(@color, (@shades * 4.9));
}

.generate-color-shades(@grey, 10%);
```

And than call it somewhere simply like:

```
@navbar-bg: @grey-550;
```

Or dynamically like that:

```
// COLORS
// -------------------------------------

@test-colors:
    grey-50    @grey-50,
    grey-100   @grey-100,
    grey-150   @grey-150,
    grey-200   @grey-200,
    grey-250   @grey-250,
    grey-300   @grey-300,
    grey-350   @grey-350,
    grey-400   @grey-400,
    grey-450   @grey-450,
    grey-500   @grey-500,
    grey-550   @grey-550,
    grey-600   @grey-600,
    grey-650   @grey-650,
    grey-700   @grey-700,
    grey-750   @grey-750,
    grey-800   @grey-800,
    grey-850   @grey-850,
    grey-900   @grey-900,
    grey-950   @grey-950,
;

.test {
    .for(@test-colors); .-each(@i) {
        @classname: extract(@i, 1);

        &-@{classname} {
            background: extract(@i, 2),
        }
    }
}
```

Of course both type of calls will cause error for obvious reasons of how LESS variables works now...

Question is - how to avoid this error and still maintain ability to simply call and treat such variables as usual with @variableSyntax call?

Should i precompile LESS files with already generated variables somehow?

Or maybe there are some new workaround i'm not aware yet?)

Thanks in advance, for any further help!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't generate variable names dynamically in Less.

And I think your code is not very maintainable because even after you generate those color variables you will be calling them directly in the other parts of your styles, which makes them not so "dynamic". Actually it's not easy to change all those variable calls if you want to change the color later.

If you think `darken` and `lighten` are not good enough, you may have to implement a Less plugin to provide your own custom function which handles your own shade parameter.